# Is this fastes way to check if IP (string) belongs to CIDR (string)?

Tags: c

Want to check if IP (as String) is in CIDR range (as String)

I know there are also some network functions to check it, but decided to use this approach and have this code so far:

```
    int cidr_to_ip_and_mask(const char *cidr, uint32_t *ip, uint32_t *mask)
    {
        uint8_t a, b, c, d, bits;
        if (sscanf(cidr, "%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu/%hhu", a, b, c, d, bits) < 5) {
            return -1; /* didn't convert enough of CIDR */
        }
        if (bits > 32) {
            return -1; /* Invalid bit count */
        }
        *ip =
            (a << 24UL) |
            (b << 16UL) |
            (c << 8UL) |
            (d);
        *mask = (0xFFFFFFFFUL << (32 - bits)) & 0xFFFFFFFFUL;
    }
    
    uint32_t netip;
    uint32_t netmask;
    if (cidr_to_ip_and_mask("10.0.0.0/16", &netip, &netmask) < 0) {
        /* return some failure */
    } 
    uint8_t a, b, c, d;
    
    char *ipstr= "10.0.0.1" // value to check
    uint32_t ip = 0;
    if (sscanf(ipstr, "%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu",  a, b, c, d) < 4) {
            return -1; /* didn't convert enough of CIDR */
        }
       
    ip = (a << 24UL) |
      (b << 16UL) |
      (c << 8UL) |
      (d);
            
    uint32_t netstart = (netip & netmask); // first ip in subnet
    uint32_t netend = (netstart | ~netmask); // last ip in subnet
    if ((ip >= netstart) && (ip <= netend))
        // is in subnet range...
    else
        // not in subnet range...
```

Is this correct?

Is this the fastest way to achieve it?

**Update**

I did some experimenting and measurements using both codes. Had to slightly modify proposed answer code.

Final code I used:

t1.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int cidr_to_ip_and_mask(const char *cidr, uint32_t *ip, uint32_t *mask)
{
    uint8_t a, b, c, d, bits;
    if (sscanf(cidr, "%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu/%hhu", &a, &b, &c, &d, &bits) < 5) {
        return -1; /* didn't convert enough of CIDR */
    }
    if (bits > 32) {
        return -1; /* Invalid bit count */
    }
    *ip =
        (a << 24UL) |
        (b << 16UL) |
        (c << 8UL) |
        (d);
    *mask = (0xFFFFFFFFUL << (32 - bits)) & 0xFFFFFFFFUL;
}

void main()
{    
    uint32_t netip;
    uint32_t netmask;


    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    {
        if (cidr_to_ip_and_mask("10.1.0.0/16", &netip, &netmask) < 0) {
            /* return some failure */
        } 
        uint8_t a, b, c, d;
        uint32_t ip;

        char *ipstr= "10.2.13.1"; // value to check
        if (sscanf(ipstr, "%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu",  &a, &b, &c, &d) < 4) {
        }

        ip = (a << 24UL) |
            (b << 16UL) |
            (c << 8UL) |
            (d);

        uint32_t netstart = (netip & netmask); // first ip in subnet
        uint32_t netend = (netstart | ~netmask); // last ip in subnet
        if ((ip >= netstart) && (ip <= netend))
            printf("in");
        else
            printf("out");
    }
}
```

t2.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(){

    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    {


        char ipAsString[16]="10.2.13.1";
        char cidrAsString[20]="10.1.0.0/16";
        char *ipSplit[4];
        unsigned char ipAddr[4];
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            if(i==0)  
                ipSplit[i] =  (char *)strtok(ipAsString, ".");
            else 
                ipSplit[i] = (char *)strtok(NULL, ".");
        }
        ipAddr[0] = atoi(ipSplit[0]);
        ipAddr[1] = atoi(ipSplit[1]);
        ipAddr[2] = atoi(ipSplit[2]);
        ipAddr[3] = atoi(ipSplit[3]);
       
        int i=0;
        for(i=0;i<=16;i++)
        {
            if(cidrAsString[i]=='/')
                break;
        }
        char c[3];
        strncpy(c,cidrAsString+(i+1),2);

        int cirdIntVal = atoi(c);
        int numOfSetBits = 0;
        if (ipAddr[0] < 255) {
            // find number of set bits (1s) in ipAddr[0] and add them to numOfSetBits
        } else if (ipAddr[1] <= 255) {
            numOfSetBits += 8;
            // find number of set bits (1s) in ipAddr[1] and add them to numOfSetBits
        } else if (ipAddr[2] <= 255) {
            numOfSetBits += 16;
            // find number of set bits (1s) in ipAddr[2] and add them to numOfSetBits
        } else {
            numOfSetBits += 24;
            // find number of set bits (1s) in ipAddr[1] and add them to numOfSetBits
        }
        if (numOfSetBits == cirdIntVal) // will return true if ip is in cird
            printf("in");
        else
            printf("out");
    }
}
```

Performance results:

```
time ./t1     
./t1  0,00s user 0,00s system 80% cpu 0,001 total
time ./t2
./t2  0,00s user 0,00s system 81% cpu 0,001 total

Above is with return value ie return 1 or 0

Below is with printf()s

time ./t1  0,66s user 0,02s system 78% cpu 0,856 total

time ./t2  0,21s user 0,00s system 52% cpu 0,406 total


Second approch is ca 47% faster and easier on CPU
```

Comment: To determine the fastest method in your environment you will have to implement several and measure them. What is the timing you need to match? Did you measure? How much do you need to optimise the timing? Are you off by a lot?

Comment: Write your own parser if you really need speed instead of using sscanf

Comment: Does it even compile?  You have uint32_t ip but you are using *ip

Comment: Thanks for all replies. Corrected the pseudocode. @Ôrel how can i do it?

Comment: *Why* do you want it to be fast? BTW: sscanf() is always slow. (since it involves a function call, and cannot be inlined)

Comment: Takes 1-100 milliseconds to get IP packet over internet.  Saves a few nano seconds in function to parse it...

Comment: @wildplasser `*scanf()` can be analysed  by the compiler and emit very efficient code - especially for simply formats.

Comment: @wildplasser  Since I write a NGINX module and will have a whitelist list (with CIDR) I want to check the SRC IP against that list (get the SRC from NGINX). If the SRC IP will be in the whitelist (CIDR range), it should be allowed and never blocked. I want to make this check very fast to decrease latency in the module/NGINX.

Comment: `if (sscanf(cidr, "%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu/%hhu", &a, &b, &c, &d, &bits) < 5) {...}` could make the code even work.

Comment: @wildplasser Modified my samples. Seems like approach without sscanf() is ca 47% faster

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear from your question, but you if you are given ip address as string or `char` array, you can go store each "decimal value" of ip into a single `unsigned char`. You do not need to convert it to 32bit value, you check each individual char, and operate on it. For example if you have `10.252.1.154` as ip, store 10, 252, 1 and 154 in variables `bits31_24`, `bits23_16`, `bits15_8`, `bits7_0`, and than you count number of continuous `1`s in each `unsigned char` from left.

```
int getCIDR (char *ipAsString, char* cird) {
    unsigned char ipAddr[4];
    char ipSplit[4][3] = strtok(ipAsString, '.');
    ipAddr[0] = atoi(ipSplit[0]);
    ipAddr[1] = atoi(ipSplit[1]);
    ipAddr[2] = atoi(ipSplit[2]);
    ipAddr[3] = atoi(ipSplit[3]);

    int numOfSetBits = 0;
    if (ipAddr[0] < 255) {
        // find number of set bits (1s) till first 0 in ipAddr[0] and add them to numOfSetBits
        return numOfSetBits;
    } else if (ipAddr[1] <= 255) {
        numOfSetBits += 8;
        // find number of set bits (1s) till first 0 in ipAddr[1] and add them to numOfSetBits
        return numOfSetBits;
    } else if (ipAddr[2] <= 255) {
        numOfSetBits += 16;
        // find number of set bits (1s) till first 0 in ipAddr[2] and add them to numOfSetBits
        return numOfSetBits;
    } else {
        numOfSetBits += 24;
        // find number of set bits (1s) in till first 0 ipAddr[1] and add them to numOfSetBits
        return numOfSetBits;
    }
}
```

Above code would return each CRDL from `\0` to `\32`

than to convert it back to string:

```
char* CLDR = malloc (sizeof(char) * (numOfDigits(numOfSetBits) + 1)); // 1 for \ character
CLDR = itoa (numberOfSetBits);
```

EDIT:
Per comment `atoi` to cut down on function calls could be re-written as

```
ipAddr[0] = (ipSplit[0][0] - '0') * 100 + (ipSplit[0][1] - '0') * 10 + ipSplit[0][0] - '0';
```

EDIT:
To suit question better and not to disturb the original code, here is the revised code.

```
int getCIDR (char *ipAsString, char* cidr) {
    unsigned char ipAddr[4];
    char ipSplit[4][3] = strtok(ipAsString, '.');
    ipAddr[0] = atoi(ipSplit[0]);
    ipAddr[1] = atoi(ipSplit[1]);
    ipAddr[2] = atoi(ipSplit[2]);
    ipAddr[3] = atoi(ipSplit[3]);
    ++cidr; // to skip initial /
    int cirdIntVal = atoi(cidr);

    int numOfSetBits = 0;
    if (ipAddr[0] < 255) {
        // find number of set bits (1s) in ipAddr[0] and add them to numOfSetBits
    } else if (ipAddr[1] <= 255) {
        numOfSetBits += 8;
        // find number of set bits (1s) in ipAddr[1] and add them to numOfSetBits
    } else if (ipAddr[2] <= 255) {
        numOfSetBits += 16;
        // find number of set bits (1s) in ipAddr[2] and add them to numOfSetBits
    } else {
        numOfSetBits += 24;
        // find number of set bits (1s) in ipAddr[1] and add them to numOfSetBits
    }

    return (numberOfSetBits == cirdIntVal); // will return true if ip is in cird
}
```

You can also have for ranges instead of `return (numberOfSetBits == cirdIntVal);` you do the range checking. I am assuming CIRD is given as numberical value from (not intiger, but string representation) between 1 and 32.

Also one thing for CIRD

```
\0 => 0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\1 => 10xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\2 => 110xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\3 => 1110xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
... // and so on
```

this is what I am using in my algorithm, maybe I was not clear initially.

[image: CIRDs]

Comment: Well, thats 4 or maybe 8 function calls. Aint gonna win you the Pullitzer prize.

Comment: @wildplasser you are right, but those functions I mentioned (especially `atoi` and `itoa`) might be rewritten as inline or really quick piece of code, especially if we know that substrings are short.

Comment: and with that in mind it will be way faster than `scanf()` family of functions.

Comment: @0x476f72616e hmmmm ... I have the CIDR and SRC IP .... I want to check if the SRC IP is in the CIDR range. What is your code doing? Getting CIDR from IP??? CIDR can be defined by user i.e 10.0.0.0/16 or 10.0.0.0/8 .... what are you doing here? Can you elaborate some more. Thanks

Comment: @dev exactly that. It is even easier when you have CIDR.

Comment: @dev this cod is easily modified to suit your needs. I can do it bit later.

Comment: @0x476f72616e would be great, since I didn't understand it yet

Comment: @dev I hope I was of any help here. I revised my code.

Comment: @0x476f72616e wow looks amazing. I guess we cannot not use strtok() and atoi(). Seems to me like the fastest approach. I will run some tests on Monday to compare sscanf() and your version, unless u know how to do it better. I want to make loop and do ie 1000000 calls and time with Linux "time" command

Comment: @dev let me know results of tests. I would love to know how does this perform

Comment: @0x476f72616e Seems like your approach is 47% faster

Comment: @0x476f72616e Hmm it seems it does not work correctly ...  `char ipAsString[16]="192.168.1.2";
        char cidrAsString[20]="192.168.1.0/24";` returns false when it should return true. The IP is in the CIDR range.

Comment: @dev sorry to hear that

Comment: @dev I will have some more time to help you out in a day or two. I think I have better approach.